# Multiple regexes in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am creating a programming language. For this language, I am creating a program that compiles it into Python. I don't need a lexer, because most of the grammar can be converted into Python with regexes.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import re

infile = input()

output = open(infile + ".py","w")
input = open(infile + ".hlx")
# I'm aware the .hlx extension is already taken, but it doesn't really matter.

for line in input:
    output.write(re.sub(r'function (\S+) (\S+) =', r'def \1(\2):', line))

for line in input:
    output.write(re.sub(r'print(.+)', r'print(\1)', line))

for line in input:
    output.write(re.sub(r'call (\S+) (\S+)', r'\1(\2)', line))

# More regexes go here, eventually.

input.close()
output.close()
```

I had to put each regex in a separate for statement because if I put them together, it would replace each line 3 times.

The problem here is that it only performs one of the regexes, which is the first one. The order doesn't really matter here, but I still need the program to perform all of the regexes. How would I do this?

By the way, here's the code I want to replace in my language:

```
function hello input =
    print "Hello, ", input, "!"
hello "world"
```

And here's the code I want to replace it with in Python:

```
def hello(input):
    print("Hello, " + input + "!")
hello("world")
```

Comment: If you want to iterate over an open file multiple times you need to `seek()` to the beginning of the file.  Also, why don't you assign the output of each `re.sub` call to a variable so you can call each `re.sub` on the same line before you have to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform one all substitutions in one loop, one after another. I also suggest having regular expressions and their replacements in a separate data structure, which would make further extensions easier:

```
conversions = (
  (r'function (\S+) (\S+) =', r'def \1(\2):'),
  (r'print(.+)',              r'print(\1)'  ),
  (r'call (\S+) (\S+)',       r'\1(\2)'     ),
)

for line in input:
    for (pattern, sub) in conversions:
        line = re.sub(pattern, sub, line)
    output.write(line)
```

Comment: By any chance, do you also know how to perform regexes in a certain order? For example: do this regex, then do this one, then do this one...

Comment: They are applied in the order of appearance in the tuple.